# why bokeh line graph gets squeezed when having set of labels to the left of the chart area?

Tags: python, layout, label, bokeh, yaxis

I have a bokeh line plot and I'm adding a series of labels to the left of the y-axis. I have also tried LabelSet but with LabelSet nothing is coming up. so I used a for loop to add all of the labels to the layout but the graph is getting squeezed to the right. any ideas?

```python
p = figure(plot_width=1000, plot_height=800, x_axis_type="datetime",
           title='String Line - Lakeshore West', sizing_mode='stretch_both')

for (key, grp), color in zip (Lakeshore_West.groupby('CourseID'), Viridis256):
    source = ColumnDataSource(dict(courseID = grp.CourseID, time=grp.Time, chainage = grp.Chainage
                                  , station=grp.Station, serviceType=grp.ServiceType))
    line = p.line('time', 'chainage', color= color, source=source)
    ttips = HoverTool(renderers = [line], tooltips = [
    ('CourseID ', ' @courseID'),
    ('Time ', ' @time{%H:%M:%S}'),
    ('Chainage ', ' @chainage'),
    ('Service Type ', ' @serviceType')],formatters={'@time': 'datetime'})
    p.add_tools(ttips)


format = '%H:%M:%S'
x_min = str(Lakeshore_West['Time'].min())
x_max = str(Lakeshore_West['Time'].max())
minDateTime = datetime.strptime(x_min, format)
maxDateTime = datetime.strptime(x_max, format)
diff = maxDateTime - minDateTime
x_centre = (diff/2 + minDateTime).time()    

for ind in trackNo.index:
    if trackNo['Corridor'][ind] == 1:
        y_centre = (trackNo['Chainage'][ind+1] - trackNo['Chainage'][ind])/2 + trackNo['Chainage'][ind]
        colors = trackNo['Color'][ind]
        tracks = trackNo['TrackNo'][ind]
        if (trackNo['Chainage'][ind+1] - trackNo['Chainage'][ind]) > 0:
            height = trackNo['Chainage'][ind+1] - trackNo['Chainage'][ind]  
            rectangle = p.rect(x=x_centre, y=y_centre, width=diff, height= height, 
                               angle=0, fill_color= colors, line_color=colors, width_units ='data', 
                               height_units='data', fill_alpha=0.2,  line_alpha=0.0,
                               legend_field = 'TrackNo')
            
LSW_sta = Lakeshore_West[['Station', 'Chainage']].drop_duplicates()      
for ind in LSW_sta.index: 
    p.add_layout(Label(x=Lakeshore_West['Time'].min(), y=LSW_sta['Chainage'][ind], x_offset=-150, y_offset=0,
                  text=LSW_sta['Station'][ind], text_font_size= "10px", render_mode='canvas'), 'left')
    
p.x_range = Range1d(Lakeshore_West['Time'].min(), Lakeshore_West['Time'].max())
p.y_range = Range1d(Lakeshore_West['Chainage'].min(), Lakeshore_West['Chainage'].max())
p.legend.visible = False 

show(p)
```

[image]

Comment: Labels were never intended to be used to far outside the plot region. I expect this extreme usage simply breaks Bokeh's canvas layout. It's possible supporting this use-case could be considered, but that would require future development work. Options: 1) make space inside the plot (axes) frame for the labels 2) add an actual proper secondary axis with a fixed ticker and tick label overrides.

Comment: @bigreddot tried option 2 and it works. I'm also thinking of creating customJS. thank you for your reply!